# Calculated Field - First letter of each word

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field

I am looking to build a calculated field in access that will be an abbreviation for company names.

What expression do I need to use?

And can this same method be used for the first 2 or 3 letters or each word?

Comment: Why a calculated field? This is something that can be done easily on a form with the LEFT function. You may lose your indexes http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html

Answer (score 0):

Write such function in some Module

```
Public Function ABBR(str As String, Optional Letters As Long = 1) As String

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim v As Variant
    arr = Split(str, " ")
    For Each v In arr
       ABBR = ABBR & Left(v, Letters)
   Next v
```

End Function

And write such in Control Source

```
 =ABBR([Field with company name],1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculated fields is not the option to go with. Calculations belong in Queries and Forms not to be in tables. This will be a lot more of a problem than you think. You need to rethink this. Allen Browne has a very good explanation of this topic : http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html

Although if you only want to be calculated in Queries and display the same in an unbound control of the Form, you could use the code provided by 4dmonster.